# OpenGL set up problem when create new project via Visual Studio express 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, properties-file

I'm using VisualStudio express 2017 as the IDE. I have set up everything for the OpenGL and everything works fine. But there is a problem, I realized that I have to set up the library and dependencies every time when I create a new project. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a solution to that called a ***Property Sheet***. Since I don't use VS Express, I'll explain how to create and reuse properties for a Visual Studio *Community Edition* project.

- **Create a new project**, for example a *C++ Console Application* (or whatever programming language you're using)
- To display **Property Manager** go to **View > Property Manager** or **View > Other Windows > Property Manager**
- In the **Property Manager**, left-click on the "triangle symbol" next to your project name to display the configurations.Choose the configuration you want to set up (here *Debug | Win32* is highlighted)

  [image: property manager window].
- Right-click on the configuration. Choose **Add New Project Property Sheet**. A property page dialog box appears. Enter a name (file extension *.props*) and where to save it. Click **Add**.
- Left-click on the "triangle symbol" next to your configuration. You should now see your newly created property sheet. Double-click on it.
- Now configure your project how you want, *include dependencies* , *libraries*, *Linker* etc.
- After configuring, right-click on your property sheet. Save it.

Now everytime you create a new project, right-click on your project name in the Property Manager and click **Add existing property sheet** and brwose to its location.